# How to compute the relative cohomology groups of a simple example?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm starting to learn homology and cohomology, and I would like to try an example to understand more concretely what's going on. Let $T$ be the 2-torus, and $S^1$ the circle. Let $i: S^1 \to T$ be an embedding. I want to compute the relative cohomology groups $H^k(T,S^1)$ in two cases: the embedding $i$ is trivial (contractible), and $i$ maps the circle once around the handle of the torus. I'm working in $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients.

I'm reading through Hatcher to try to solve this, and I see two ways to approach it. Using the long exact sequence of cohomology, and doing everything from scratch using cocycles and so on. I tried the long exact sequence but I couldn't see how to use the specific embeddings to get an answer. And I'm pretty much lost when it comes to doing it from scratch. All I know is that in homology, the trivial embedding of the circle is a boundary since it is the manifold-boundary of a submanifold (a disc), while the non-trivial embedding is a cycle that is not a boundary. So the homology class of the first is $0$ while that of the second is non zero. I don't understand the cohomology counterpart to these facts.

Could I get some guidance for this problem?

Comment: I would recommend using the long exact sequence.  Where exactly do you get stuck using it?

Comment: Alternatively, another approach is to identify $H^*(T,S^1)$ with $\tilde{H}^*(T/S^1)$ and understand what the quotient space $T/S^1$ looks like.

Comment: @EricWofsey Following page 200 of Hatcher, I get $0 \to H^0 (T,S^1) \to \mathbb{Z}$ at the beginning of the LES, and from what I can tell, $H^0$ must be either 0 or $Z$ but I can't see how to decide which one it is. I guess my difficulty lies in understanding how the three induced maps $i^*, j^*$ and $\delta$ work.

Comment: The crucial ingredient is to figure out what the $i^*$ maps are (which you can do since you are told what $i$ is).

Comment: Okay, thanks! And just to clarify, I can replace each $H^k(T,S^1)$ with $\tilde{H}^k(T/S^1)$ and the LES doesn't change? And also, would the quotient $T/S^1$ from the trivial embedding be the torus wedged with a 2-sphere? And from the non-trivial embedding, a sphere with 2 distinct points identified?

Comment: Yes to all of those (except that I'm not entirely sure what you mean by the first question--what LES involving $\tilde{H}^k(T/S^1)$ are you talking about?).

Comment: Maybe I'm confusing the notation but I'm assuming that you're saying $H^* (T,S^1) \cong \tilde{H}^* (T/S^1)$, which should mean $H^k (T,S^1) \cong \tilde{H}^k (T/S^1)$, right? In which case the LES of cohomology with $T, S^1$ and the relative pairs have the pairs replaced with the quotients.

Comment: I mean, sure, you can replace each $H^k (T,S^1)$ with $\tilde{H}^k (T/S^1)$ in the LES via the isomorphisms to get another LES.  But this is just an obvious property of isomorphisms (you did the same thing when you replaced $H^0(T)$ with $\mathbb{Z}$, for instance).

Comment: @EricWofsey Thanks for all the help! I think I got an answer, I posted it here.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, with the help of Eric Wofsey's hints, I think I have an answer to my question.

First we have that $H^k(T,S^1) \cong \tilde{H}^k (T/S^1)$ for all $k$, where the quotient map is induced from the embedding of the circle. (I cannot find a reference for this fact.) Note that whenever a (nice enough?) space is path connected, the $0$th reduced homology is always $0$.

Now in the first case, let $S^1$ be embedded in $T$ such that it is contractible. Then $T/S^1$ is a torus wedge a $2$-sphere. Call this space $X_1$. Using the Mayer-Vietoris sequence, we get that $\tilde{H}^k (X_1) \cong \tilde{H}^k (T) \oplus \tilde{H}^k (S^2)$. The summands are widely known, so we get that

\begin{equation}
H^k(T,S^1) \cong
  \begin{cases}
  0 & \text{if}\ k=0\\
  \mathbb{Z}^2 & \text{if}\ k=1,2\\
  0 & \text{if}\ k \geq 3.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Next, the second case, where $S^1$ is wrapped once around the handle of the torus, we get that $T/S^1$ is the [pinched torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinched_torus), and the wiki contains its cohomology groups. Changing the $0$th to be $0$, we get that

\begin{equation}
H^k(T,S^1) \cong
  \begin{cases}
  0 & \text{if}\ k=0\\
  \mathbb{Z} & \text{if}\ k=1,2\\
  0 & \text{if}\ k \geq 3.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

The next challenge would be to apply this to other non-trivial loops in the torus.

Comment: The isomorphism between relative and reduced-of-the-quotient is done for homology somewhere in Hatcher chapter 2, I think section 2 thereof. It's somewhere in the middle of the section; I think you want to look for a phrase like "reduced homology of a good pair" or "relative homology of a good pair."

Comment: Since that's done with homology, we can translate this to cohomology as well?